# Gitlab pull access denied for registry

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-registry

We migrated our old Ubuntu 16.04 Gitlab Server to a new Ubuntu 20.04.

We running the gitlab image registry for our deployments. After the migration I have a strange problem, some user can no longer pull the image. The CI / CD Pipline is failing with the message:

> ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image "registry.domain.com/pathtoimage/image:version" with specified policies [always]: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for registry.domain.com/pathtoimage/image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied (manager.go:203:0s)

On the other hand I an most of the other developers can run the Pipline without problem:

> Pulling docker image registry.domain.com/pathtoimage/image:version

So I did some tests, if I am using the following commands on my local machine:

```
docker login registry.domain.com -u username
```

> Login Succeeded

```
docker pull registry.domain.com/pathtoimage/image:version
```

> Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.domain.com/pathtoimage/image:version

But if the affected user is executing the same:

```
docker login registry.domain.com -u affected_username
```

> Login Succeeded

```
docker pull registry.domain.com/pathtoimage/image:version
```

> Error response from daemon: pull access denied for registry.domain.com/pathtoimage/image:version, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

So the user could login, but has no permission to pull the image, strange. How can I grant a user the permission for the Gitlab registry? Or how can I restore the permission for the affected users?

Comment: Okay, did some further tests. The repo that created the images only had a part of the users as members. After I gave the affected user the "Reporter" privilege, he was able to download the image. Now the question, why was it working before I migrated the server. And is there a way to allow access for all user to the registry without adding them to this repo.